# How can I convert word numbers to ints in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, io

This is a follow up from my previous question. The code I have asks the user to input the digits of a number as a character array to output the number in its word form. For example inputs "2, 13, 20, 54" output "two, thirteen, twenty, fifty four". The code only works for numbers less than 100, and since the input is a character array, if any number with 3 or more digits is entered, an error message is presented notifying the user that the number is greater than or equal to 100. Is there anyway to use this code to do the reverse? For instance if the user inputs "sixty one" the output would be "61" and if the user enters "one hundred twenty seven" the output would be an error message since the number is greater than ninety nine. I used this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/ to start my work and most other solutions I've come across are in python and I have no experience but my assignment requires a solution in C. Is there anyway to assign integer values to there respective strings? such as "one: 1, eleven: 11, twenty: 20, etc." Would I have to include "hundreds, thousands, millions, etc" in my code or is there a way for my code to throw an error if strings are detected other than what i already have listed to indicate that a number is greater than 99? For example if i input "one thousand six hundred fifty" since "thousand" and "hundred" do not appear in singledig, doubledig, or multiplesoften, this indicates that the number is too large? I suspect a loop would be necessary to go through the input string to detect this but how would i go about creating an array of strings using my input?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convertnumtostring(char *num){
    int len = strlen(num);
    if(len==0){
        fprintf(stderr, "empty string\n");
        return;
    }
    if(len>2){
        fprintf(stderr, "number is is equal to or greater than 100\n");
        return;
    }

    char *singledig[]={"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    char *doubledig[]={"", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
    char *multiplesoften[]={"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

    printf("\n%s: ", num);
    if(len==1){
        printf("%s\n", singledig[*num - '0']);
        return;
    }

        if(*num == '1'){
            int sum = *num - '0' + *(num + 1)- '0';
            printf("%s\n", doubledig[sum]);
            return;
        } else if(*num == '2' && *(num + 1) == '0'){
            printf("twenty\n");
            return;
        } else {
            int i = *num - '0';
            printf("%s ", i? multiplesoften[i]: "");
            ++num;
            if(*num != '0')
                printf("%s ", singledig[*num - '0']);
        }
}

int main(void){
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    convertnumtostring(input);
    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: If you only need to recognize perfect, exact matches, you can just loop through all 100 possibilities and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i don't see any other way in which you can do this question. For your question on cases for million and thousands, yes you would have to include cases for which if that word is there you can assign a variable with that number. One thing you can do is to separate the the words into different strings based on spacing between. This would make the code much more easier and then compare using strcmp.
For example : one hundread and thirty one.

```
str1 = one
str2 = hundred
str3 = and
str4 = thirty
str5 = one

strcmp(str1,result[i])
```

//result[i] is a 2 dimensional array containing all possible values like in your program .  You will need to iterate through the cases as well.

Also in the 2 dimensional array you can keep the most probable values to occur first. That is thirty,forty etc.

For single digits you can check length of sting and avoid this checking and call another function so that time complexity doesn't increase.
This is one solution i can think of.